# Interrupt implementation for msp430 microcontroller

Tags: msp430

Can anyone explain me how to implement msp430 interrupts I need to work for uart interrupts . what does it means USCI_A2_VECTOR ??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this before you post any more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the various tutorials available:

https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/420.php
http://www.simplyembedded.org/tutorials/msp430-uart/

As for the interrupt vectors themself - have a look at the familiy guide for your MSP, there you will find which vectors exists, how they are named, and in which cases they are used.

For a more specific answer you will need to provide more details and in which issues to got. See Maciej Jureczkos comment for a link how to ask here ;)